# How to hide module drop down in open cart 2

Tags: php, opencart

I am new to Open cart.

I am want to hide the drop down arrow list of the module in the open cart admin panel. After hide in module only see the module list not the Payment gateway etc. I don't know what settings and how to change in hard code files. If anybody knows please tell me.
Thank You.

Comment: Hi, Which version of OpenCart?

Comment: Opencart Version:2.1.0.2

Answer (score 0):

for this just go into Admin > View > Template > Common > menu.tpl

Search for this:
`<li><a href="<?php echo $module; ?>"><?php echo $text_module; ?></a></li>`

And remove it or you can add class "hidden" in <li>

If you don't want to hard code it. You can also do it via VQmod.